# Add class to dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, addclass, dynamic-content

I have a shared left menu in a separate file from my pages so that I can update it in one place.

I am loading it onto the page in a .js file like so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#left-nav").load("templates/left-nav.html", function() {
        ...
    });

    ...
}
```

I would like to be able to set the nav-list item for the page to be selected. Something like this:

```
$("#calendar").addClass("selected");
```

...where #calendar is the ID of a list item in my left-nav.html template file.

Everything I've read says that I have to call addClass as a callback after I load in the file, but the following doesn't seem to work:

```
$(function () {
    $("#left-nav").load("templates/left-nav.html", function() {
        $("#calendar").addClass("selected");
    });

    ...
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to add classes to dynamically added content on a page, and if so, how should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the results have an element with the ID of `calendar`? In your text you say the id is `#calendar` I just want to confirm that that's a typo and that you meant the query is `#calendar` and the ID is `calendar`

Comment: After you load the template, in the console, what does `$('#calendar').length` output?

Comment: Can you post `templates/left-nav.html` HTML?

Comment: The `load()` callback is fired immediately after the request succeeds, and not necessarily after the content loads. Consider using `get()` and a `complete` function. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get

Comment: God bless America. @Shriike caught my error. That fixed it -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct as written, adduming that `left-nav.html` does contain an element with the ID of `calendar`.

The completed event is fired after the HTML is added to the DOM according to the jQuery documentation.